# Is there any simple way to control marquee speed in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

"Used marquee attributes"

```
 android:ellipsize="marquee"
 android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
 android:scrollHorizontally="true"
 android:singleLine = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no... If you really need something different you will have to  make your own TextView translation animation (if that is the case I suggest you to read the Animation documentation) https://developer.android.com/training/animation